# Does atomic_refresh=>false in dbms_mview.refresh procedure rebuild index?

Tags: oracle, index

Recently I've receive some alerts of unusable materialized view indexes and it happens when a materialized view is refreshed. The materialized view is refreshed with this command:

```
exec dbms_mview.refresh('MY_MV',atomic_refresh=>false);
```

`atomic_refresh=>false` always make the index unusable and then rebuild it? or could be other reason? I guess it make sense since `atomic_refresh=>false` truncate the table and probably rebuild the index is faster?

Answer (score 1):

Do the indexes become usable again after refresh? If yes, you have probably explained the reason.

Actually, during non-atomic refresh, even the MView is not unusable. Who care about the indexes in that period?

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure about how to explain why the index unusable alert open every day, but make sense.